# User photo gallery that another user can view

Tags: views, nodes

I'm looking to give my user the ability to to have a personal photo gallery that when another user clicks on their profile they can see said gallery?

I know i can create a content type and view, but not sure where to go from there as far as only exposing the necessary photos for a specific user to another. basically a dumb-ed down version of what Facebook has as far as photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some interesting options, take a look at the [Album Photos module](https://www.drupal.org/project/photos). I'm not sure if it will do what you're asking OOB, but if you use it, it would change your question so I'll suggest it.

> "Album Photos" is an image album module providing multi-user album
>   features. The module development objective is to provide a
>   comprehensive image album solution for Drupal.
>
> Version 7.x-3.x Highlights
>
> Integrates with core image styles. Uses Libraries API 2.x for
>   Jeditable. Built in support for Colorbox. Vote on images with Voting
>   API. Comment on images. Built in support for Plupload. Upload multiple
>   images with Plupload. Limit the number of albums created per role.
>   Reads image exif parameters. Nice presentation of the images. Views
>   integration. Support for private file system. Drag and drop interface
>   to re arrange photos and albums to sort by custom weight order. Photos
>   Access Included as a sub module. Enable this module to control who has
>   access to the photos and galleries.
>
> Create password protected photo galleries. Create galleries with a
>   list of collaborators who can edit the same gallery. Create private /
>   locked galleries that can only be seen / edited by the gallery owner.
>   photo gallery, image gallery, user managed photo albums

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image field to the profile fields rather than use a node and content type, under configuration and account settings choose manage fields and add it there.

If you do want to use a content type and a node, add a reference to node:author and add a contextual filter with a default value to get user ID from URL, that will only show the images from the node(s) that user has created.